# No readline support while using pdb.set_trace()

Tags: python, readline, pdb, libreadline

I have an application running Python 2.6.X. Starting the Python interpreter in interactive mode (with or without using virtualenv): readline support working (command history).
Starting my application with the same Python interpreter (virtualenv-ed or not): no readline support available when using **pdb.set_trace()**: cursor keys not working. Operating system is Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Check this recipe to enable readline support in pdb

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498182-sane-tab-completion-in-pdb/

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and for me the solution was to use the set trace command that comes with django instead of the pdb package.